# Problem in creating QFile inside a location other than the current directory

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I am using Qt 4.7 installed on Ubuntu 10.04 .... 
I can't create a qt file inside a location other than the current directory "."

This code works well:

```
QFile file("data.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::Append))
{
    qDebug("ERROR WHILE OPENING THE FILE TO APPEND Data");
    return ;
}
```

but this code fails (I think because of the permissions):

```
QFile file("/var/lib/mysql/testdb/data.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::Append))
{
    qDebug("ERROR WHILE OPENING THE FILE TO APPEND Data");
    return ;
}
```

So, how can I solve this problem and give the program permissions to create the file wherever at the file system??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve this quickly in one of these ways:

- Run as root (this is a big no-no)
- As root, change the permissions of the directory you need, `chmod /the/dir o+rwx` - this lets **everyone** write to the directory.
- As root, change the owner of the directory you need, `chown myuser /the/dir` - this lets **your** user write to the directory.

You solve this **correctly** by sticking to directories that your current user can access - permissions are there for a reason.